# open a modal popup from another modalpopup is possible?

Tags: jquery

I want to open a modalpopup from another modalpopup.Is it possible in Jquery?

Comment: Which modal plug-in are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The point of a modal window is that you cannot do anything else until that modal window has been dismissed, so opening another modal would defeat the object of the modal window in the first place so i doubt anyone would programme it. Having said that the modal windows in jquery are hacks so it may be possible.

Comment: Apparently, the developers where I work seem to think otherwise, ugh. *sigh*